# phpmyadmin showing myisam instead of innodb

Tags: sql, mysql

my phpmyadmin showing the table type are myisam ,

but my tables are innodb, Why it is showing as myisam , [image]

Comment: i just created table using gui not an query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MyISAM` is the default storage engine on your server.

You'll note that next to each table it says `InnoDB`.  *Your tables are InnoDB.*  The final `MyISAM` is only there in the footer to indicate the default setting for your MySQL server.

To change the default:

> If you omit the ENGINE or TYPE option,
>   the default storage engine is used.
>   Normally, this is MyISAM, but you can
>   change it by using the
>   --default-storage-engine or --default-table-type server startup option, or by setting the
>   default-storage-engine or
>   default-table-type option in the
>   my.cnf configuration file.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-engines.html

If you are in a shared hosting environment—which is likely since you are using phpmyadmin—you may not be able to change the default.  But it is largely irrelevant, since it's only used if you omit the declaration when creating a new table.  Since you select `InnoDB` when creating tables, all of your tables are `InnoDB` not `MyISAM`

Comment: Then is is possible to change that mysql server default one